# Menu Responsivo com submenu dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, css

Estou trabalhando em um menu modelo e preciso ajustar a exibição do submenu. Eu não consigo fazer o submenu se sobrepor ao menu original. Quando passo o mouse pelo link do submenu, ele é exibido, porém, ele expande não só o submenu, mas também a div do menu. Segue código:

```js
 function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
  if (x.className === "topnav") {
   x.className += " responsive";
  } else {
   x.className = "topnav";
  }
 }
```

```css
body {
 width: 90%;
 margin-left: 5%;
 background-color: #A19BFF;
}
.listsubmenu{
 display: none;
 width: 180px;
 list-style-type: none;
}
.listsubmenu li{
 width: 180px;
}
#menuprincipal{
 background-color: #FEFEFE; 
 position: relative;
 margin: 0;
}
#dropdown:hover .listsubmenu{
 display: block;
 position: relative;
}
ul.topnav {
 list-style-type: none;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 overflow: hidden;
}
ul.topnav li {
 float: left;
}
ul.topnav li a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #3E4095;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 17px;
  border-radius: 50px;
}
ul.topnav li a:hover {
 background-color: #3E4095;
 color: white;
}
ul.listsubmenu li a:hover{
 width: 150px;
}
ul.topnav li.icon {
 display: none;
}
@media screen and (max-width:680px) {
 ul.topnav li:not(:first-child) {
  display: none;
 }
 ul.topnav li.icon {
  float: right;
  display: inline-block;
 }
 ul.topnav.responsive li.icon {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
 } 
 ul.topnav.responsive li {
  float: none;
  display: inline;
 }
 ul.topnav.responsive li a {
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
 }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset='utf-8'>
 <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='css\normalize.css'>
 <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='css\menu_responsivo.css'>
</head>
<body>
 <nav id='menuprincipal'>
  <ul class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
   <li><a class="active" href="#home">Início</a></li>
   <li><a href="#news">Sobre Nós</a></li>
   <li id='dropdown'><a href="#contact">Sistemas</a>
    <ul class='listsubmenu'>
     <li><a href=''>Auto Peças</a></li>
     <li><a href=''>Esfiharia</a></li>
     <li><a href=''>Estacionamentos</a></li>
     <li><a href=''>Mercados</a></li>
     <li><a href=''>Pet Shops</a></li>
     <li><a href=''>Pizzarias</a></li>
     <li><a href=''>Restaurantes</a></li>
    </ul>
   </li>
   <li><a href="#about">Cliente</a></li>
   <li><a href="#about">Contato</a></li>
   <li class="icon">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:15px;" onclick="myFunction()">☰</a>
   </li>
  </ul>
 </nav>
 <div style="padding-left:16px">
   <h2>Responsive Topnav Example</h2>
   <p>Resize the browser window to see how it works.</p>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

**Olá Mateus, talvez se você manipular um pouco seu CSS você pode fazer algo do tipo:**

```css
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
}

li {
    float: left;
}

li a, .dropbtn {
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: red;
}

li.dropdown {
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 </head>
<body>
<ul>
  <li><a class="active" href="#home">Início</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">Sobre nós</a></li>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropbtn">Sistemas</a>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Auto Peças</a>
      <a href="#">Esfiharia</a>
      <a href="#">Estacionamentos</a>
      <a href="#">Mercados</a>
      <a href="#">Pet Shops</a>
      <a href="#">Pizzarias</a>
      <a href="#">Restaurantes</a>



    </div>
  </li>
</ul>

<h3>Dropdown Menu inside a Navigation Bar</h3>
<p>Hover over the "Dropdown" link to see the dropdown menu.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

[Exemplos de DropDown W3C](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_dropdowns.asp)

Comment: Valeu Fabricio. Tinha deixado de lado o script até agora.